# Javascript stops working as expected when extension is changed from html to php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two identical files. The only difference is the extension. Yet Javascript in both files does things differently. Basically the javascipt that I have controls the height of the page but it starts setting the height to something abnormal when the extension is php.

There are both pages:
http://test.lu-creative.com/users/tables_dynamic.html,
http://test.lu-creative.com/users/tables_dynamic.php

Notice that the PHP one needs scrolling but not the other one. Both use the same javascript function.

The javascript code that handles the height is:

```
$RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', $(window).height());


var bodyHeight = $BODY.outerHeight(),
    footerHeight = $BODY.hasClass('footer_fixed') ? -10 : $FOOTER.height(),
    leftColHeight = $LEFT_COL.eq(1).height() + $SIDEBAR_FOOTER.height(),
    contentHeight = bodyHeight < leftColHeight ? leftColHeight : bodyHeight;
// normalize content
contentHeight -= $NAV_MENU.height() + footerHeight;
console.log(contentHeight);
$RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', contentHeight);
//$RIGHT_COL.css('min-height', '2000px');
```

The files can be found at this repo: 
https://github.com/Kunwark/kkcms/tree/master/public/users

Comment: Something is clearly different between the two. view source.

Comment: @blackandorangecat two identical pages don't render differently.

Comment: I don't view 3rd party links, so i can't confirm/deny the results.

Comment: something has got to be different. Use the HTML version, stage it to a commit in git, and then paste in the PHP version.

Comment: Exactly that's what bugging me.... These are to same pages but they render differently. just cuz of the extension. If you check the javascript  itis same for both executes differently for both pages.

Comment: The `.php` file is probably being read and interpreted as PHP source, which almost certainly does *something*. Why would you give a plain HTML source file a `.php` extension anyway?

Comment: tldr, the browser doesn't know php. The backend being php or a static html file is entirely irrelevant the the browser. It isn't going to render differently because the extension is .html, or .php, or even .clownfart. If it's rendering differently, it's because it is actually different. Check the headers, the content length, check that the same js is being included/executed, etc

Comment: I just created an empty git repository, put in the HTML version of the page and committed. I then copy/pasted the PHP source of the page, and saved. No differences found in my editor.

Comment: @KevinB, it's the same file I am committing git  changes once that is done. I'll share the link to the repository.

Comment: @Pointy, I have to break this one into php template but can't get the javascript to work fine.

Comment: Look you haven't even mentioned what JavaScript you're talking about. That page imports many scripts.

Comment: Could very well be caching for all we know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is in Custom.js line 5036:

```
// check active menu
$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a[href="' + CURRENT_URL + '"]').parent('li').addClass('current-page');

$SIDEBAR_MENU.find('a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == CURRENT_URL;//5036
}).parent('li').addClass('current-page').parents('ul').slideDown(function() {
    setContentHeight();
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

You're resizing magic is based on the urls matching. The problem is this.href contains a url that ends in tables_dynamic.html in both pages, so the tables_dynamic.php will never match.

Comment: you da real mvp

Comment: let me try fixing this.